# how to get name value associated with integer in dto

Tags: java, dto

i'm using java, for example, i have 2 tables `staff`(id, name, status_id, company_id) and `company`(id, name), the corresponding entity looks like:

```
public class Staff {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer statusId;
    private Integer companyId;
    private Company company;
}


public class Company {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private List<Staff> staffList;
}
```

for `status_id` of table `staff`, `0 means New, 1 represents Active and 2 stands for Inactive`.

I need to show `New`, `Active` or `Inactive` on html page/excel when describe a staff status rather than 0, 1 or 2.

And I have a `StaffDto`:

```
public class StaffDto {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer statusId;
    private String companyName;
}
```

my questions are:

1. the `statusName`(New/Active/Inactive) should be in `StaffDto`, such that there is no need to calculate `status name` according to `statusId` on each client, right?
2. what is a good practice to get `statusName` base on `statusId`?
   I should write code like

```
public class StaffDto {

    private Integer statusId;
    private String  statusName;

    public String getStatusName() {
        switch(statusId) {
        case 0: return "New";
        case 1: return "Active";
        case 2: return "Inactive";
        }
    }
}
```

is this a good practice? or something else(e.g. enum) is better?

3. if the logic of getting `status name` is added in `StaffDto`, what if there is another dtoj(e.g. `ADto`) also need to show `status name`, then I have to re-write this logic in `ADto`?
4. what if one client need to show `New`, `Active` or `Inactive`, while another client need to show `A`, `B` or `C` or something else, then what should I return in `StaffDto`? do I still return `New`, `Active` or `Inactive` in `StaffDto`, and other client need to calculate `N`, `A` or `I` base on `statusId` on their client? or should I return something else to client instead of xxxDto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too would go for `enum` as you mentioned, bind the status code to the name
then, you do not have to rewrite the logic in `DTO`s, Make your model have the `enum` rather than code or name

enum can have its own methods like `getShortName` for different representations

```
enum Status {
    NEW(0), Active(1), InActive(2);
    private final int code;

    Status(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getShortName() {
        return this.name().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean add `Status` enum to dto like `public class StaffDto { private Status status;}`?

Comment: Yes, that way you can get any form of status required, `StaffDto` doesn't have to have the status logic